# Elastic Search Shard/Routing

Tags: elasticsearch, multi-tenant

I have a multi-tenant system and I am trying to design ElasticSearch to support multi-tenancy. I've searched on the net but all post I've found does not specify in practice how to do it. 
The basic idea is to have on each index, 1 shard per customer and use custom routing to query the customer dedicated shard. This is clear. Now, how can I implement this? How can create multiple shards per index specifying the "key value" in order to query that specific shard in future? Code example will be helpful.

Thank you so much.

Comment: This might be worth reading: https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-multi-tenancy (old post but still pretty accurate)

Comment: I have already read it, but I need a help how to implement solution.

Comment: But then you also saw that this is not a good idea and you should find a different solution?

Comment: Hi @MassimoLavermicocca, have you checked my answer? has been of any use to you?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this is the correct way to achieve multi-tenancy, not at the shard-level.

What do you want to achieve exactly? I'd assume that you want that different users (or, better, different roles) can access different portions of an index. In this case, you should have a look at [document-level security permissions](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-overview/6.6/document-level-security.html).

How to achieve this in practice? Let's say that you have an index named `multitenants-index`, and you have two tenants such that: (i) the first tenant can read/write only those documents having the field `"tenant": 1`, (ii) the second tenant can read/write only those documents having the field `"tenant": 2`. Then, you might create the following two roles:

```
POST /_xpack/security/role/first_tenant
{
  "indices": [
    {
      "names": [ "multitenants-index" ],
      "privileges": [ "read", "write" ],
      "query": "{\"match\": {\"tenant\": 1}}"
    }
  ]
}

POST /_xpack/security/role/second_tenant
{
  "indices": [
    {
      "names": [ "multitenants-index" ],
      "privileges": [ "read", "write" ],
      "query": "{\"match\": {\"tenant\": 2}}"
    }
  ]
}
```